# Cake model bake Error: The datasource configuration "493" was not found in database.php

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model, cakephp-bake

I’m using Cakephp 2.4.1. I’m baking cake models having table name roles but I got following Error on console

```
Creating file C:\wamp\www\projectnexus\app\Model\Role.php

Error: The datasource configuration "493" was not found in database.php
```

it comes after

```
Look okay? (y/n)
[y] >
array(0) {
}
Notice Error: Undefined offset: 0 in [C:\wamp\www\projectnexus\lib\Cake\Console\Com
mand\Task\TemplateTask.php, line 79]
```

Previously, I’ve baked many models, this time I don’t know what happen. 
I tried to bake already baked models for verification, it is giving me same error. My connection is okay because rest of my application is running smoothly.

Please help

Comment: do you have something else before this error ?

Comment: see my question, I've updated it

Comment: remove those models and backed again. if still persist, may be the naming convention of models (plural name) is violated ? if it's not. please put your models name here so that i can check and tell exactly what error done by you?